# How to count filtered elements of an array in JasperPrint/iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

On my JasperPrint-Report, I have an array of `Customer`: `$P{customers}`

A customer looks like this:

```
class Customer {
  private String name;
  private Date birthDate;

  // constructor, getters and setters ...
}
```

In a textfield on my report, I want to show the number of childrens (less than 18 years old). I tried following textfield expression:

```
java.util.Arrays.stream($P{customers})
    .filter(customer -> ((java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() - customer.getBirthDate().getTime()) / (float) (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)) < 18)
    .count()
```

However Java 8 Streams are not supported and I am not allowed to enable it by my company. I get following exception when the report is compiled in Java:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
...\Reports\temp\ReservationConfirmation_1510745430519_703593.java:696: error: illegal start of expression
    .filter(customer -> ((java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() ... //$JR_EXPR_ID=91$
                     ^
```

So my question is: How can I implement such a count on my report? Is it somehow possible to implement that in a variable expression?

Comment: The Java8 streams are supported - you should use last version of JR (6.x)

Comment: You can use scriptlet as alternative

Comment: I am also not allowed to use a higher version of JasperReport.

Comment: I am not familiar with JasperReport scriplets. I will take a look at it. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: [JasperReports - Scriptlet Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/scriptlet/)